# My CUDA nvprof 'API Trace' and 'GPU Trace' are not synchronized - what to do?

Tags: cuda, profiling, trace, data-synchronization, nvprof

I'm using the CUDA 7.0 profiler, `nvprof`, to profile some process making CUDA calls:

```
$ nvprof -o out.nvprof /path/to/my/app
```

Later, I generate two traces: the 'API trace' (what happens on the host CPU, e.g. CUDA runtime calls and ranges you mark) and the 'GPU trace' (kernel executions, memsets, H2Ds, D2Hs and so on):

```
$ nvprof -i out.nvprof --print-api-trace --csv 2>&1 | tail -n +2 > api-trace.csv
$ nvprof -i out.nvprof --print-gpu-trace --csv 2>&1 | tail -n +2 > gpu-trace.csv
```

Every record in each of the traces has a timestamp (or a start and end time). The thing is, time value 0 in these two traces is not the same: The GPU trace time-0 point seems to signify when the first operation on the GPU triggered by the relevant process begins to execute, while the API trace's time-0 point seems to be the beginning of process execution, or sometime thereabouts.

I've also noticed that when I use `nvvp` and import `out.nvprof`, the values are corrected, that it to say, the start time of the first GPU op is not 0, but something more realistic.

How do I obtain the correct offset between the two traces?

Comment: If you ask for both at the same time, I don't see any "offset". `nvprof --print-gpu-trace --print-api-trace ./my_app`  Are you doing something different?  Do you see something different?  Is there some reason you can't ask for both at the same time from `nvprof` ?  [Here](http://pastebin.com/7z2mFhbB) is an example of what I see.  Note that I've marked a few lines for comparison with <<...>>

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Edited to clarify.

Comment: how about `nvprof -i out.nvprof --print-gpu-trace --print-api-trace --csv 2>&1 | tail -n +2 > comb-trace.csv`

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Hmmph. Whaddaya know. Make that an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be obvious from [the `nvprof` documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview), but it is possible to specify both `--print-gpu-trace` and `--print-api-trace` when requesting output from `nvprof`, whether you are profiling an app or extracting information from a previously captured profiler output file.

If you are profiling an app, the following should generate a "harmonized" timeline for both API activity and GPU activity:

```
nvprof --print-gpu-trace --print-api-trace ./my_app
```

You can save the output using the [`--log-file` option](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#redirecting-output).

Similarly, if you are extracting output from a previously captured output file (not the same thing as a log file), you can do something like the following:

```
nvprof -i profiler_out_file --print-gpu-trace --print-api-trace ...
```

where `profiler_out_file` should be the name of the file you previously saved using [the `nvprof -o ...` option](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#export-import).

Printing both traces with the same command is essential here for the two (combined) timelines to begin at the same point in time; if you issue two commands, each printing another trace, they may not be thus 'harmonized'.